# how to get the employee id and put it in other element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate creation of user at these web site.

when I create user, i get an ID number of the new employee, i took these ID and put it inside the element at the Employees table.

However it says that element is not founded there.

However it looks correct but maybe i missed something? Could someone let me know what i am missing here.My function for these:

```
public void IDCompare() {
    waitVisibility(empIDField);
    employeeID = getAttribute(empIDField, IDattribute);
    moveToElement(pimTab, employeeListTab);
    waitVisibility(employeeIDINTable);
    Assert.assertEquals ((getText(employeeIDINTable)), employeeID);
}
```

the element at the table is :

```
    By employeeIDINTable = By.xpath("(//tr[contains(.,"+employeeID+")]/td/a)[1])");
```

the attribute i take from the employee is :

```
String IDattribute = "value";
```

the error i get from the TestNG is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: (//tr[contains(.,0)]/td/a)[1]) (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

Comment: Post a link to the page or at least the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are using the wrong locator to identify an employee id which you have created.

Try to use the below xPath which will identify the passed employee id row from the table :

```
//a[contains(text(), 'pass employee id here')]
```

for example like below :

```
//a[contains(text(), '0017')]
```

Suppose you are fetching and storing the `actual employee id` like below

```
String actualEmployeeID = driver.findElement(By.id("employeeId")).getAttribute("value").trim();
```

then try to modify your `IDCompare()` function little bit so that it is readable and easy to understand apply the above mentioned xpath here :

```
public void idCompare() throws Exception {
    // Wait for sometime
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    // Get expected employee id from the table
    String expectedEmployeeID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), '"+actualEmployeeID+"')]")).getText().trim();
    // Compare actual and the expected values
    Assert.assertEquals(actualEmployeeID, expectedEmployeeID);
}
```

If you are still finding the difficulty then below is the whole code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class EmployeeID {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("Your site name");

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class);
        WebElement username = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername"));
            }
        });

        WebElement password = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));
            }
        });

        WebElement submit = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));
            }
        });

        // Enter your site user name
        username.sendKeys("Enter Username here");
        // Enter your site password
        password.sendKeys("Enter Password here");
        submit.click();

        WebElement pim = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("menu_pim_viewPimModule"));
            }
        });

        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(pim).build().perform();

        WebElement addEmployee = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("menu_pim_addEmployee"));
            }
        });

        addEmployee.click();

        WebElement firstName = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("firstName"));
            }
        });


        WebElement middleName = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("middleName"));
            }
        });


        WebElement lastName = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("lastName"));
            }
        });


        firstName.sendKeys("Arya");
        middleName.sendKeys("Stark");
        lastName.sendKeys("Starky");

        WebElement getEmployeeID = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("employeeId"));
            }
        });

        String employeeID = getEmployeeID.getAttribute("value");

        WebElement save = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave"));
            }
        });

        save.click();

        WebElement employeeList = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("menu_pim_viewEmployeeList"));
            }
        });

        employeeList.click();

        WebElement newlyCreatedEmployeeInTable  = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='"+employeeID+"']"));
            }
        });

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", newlyCreatedEmployeeInTable);

        System.out.println(employeeID+" is in the Table ? "+newlyCreatedEmployeeInTable.getText().trim().equals(employeeID));
    }

}
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188221/discussion-on-answer-by-ali-cse-how-to-get-the-employee-id-and-put-it-in-other-e).

Comment: Thank you @BhargavRao, but I don't know how to move to chat from the comments. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Click on the link, you'll get to the chat page. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188221/discussion-on-answer-by-ali-cse-how-to-get-the-employee-id-and-put-it-in-other-e :)

Comment: @Ali CSE it works too , and not even needs for the scroll down

Comment: Yes @shlomi, it works without scrolling down also - for checking purpose I have done the scroll down so you can ignore that part if you want to. Please accept and up vote my answer if it works or helpful to you... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

every thing is find with my code, 
the locator is `By employeeIDINTable = By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),"+employeeID+")]");`
the only thing is that i need to enter again the `By employeeIDINTable = By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),"+employeeID+")]");` at the methood since the `employeeID` is initialized only in the method.
these is the solution